# PHP extract data from mysqlDatabase

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting started with PHP and I wanted to know if there is a way that you can extract data from the DB in a model.

If I have a Users table in my DB, I'm looking for something like Users.all in rails that will use the model to extract all the entires in the Database.

Does PHP offer that type of functionality?

Comment: I don't know about how it compares to Rails, but have you looked at [Eloquent and its models?](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure php doesn't provide an ORM out of the box ( I suppose you can install a package or something), but if you are using Laravel (since the tag in your question), you need to create a model (supposing you have a migration for users_table)

`php artisan make:model user`

then simply 'use' the model in any controller

`use App\User`

and get all users :

`$users = User::all();`

Answer (score 2):

The closest to Rails is Laravel. Laravel's database layer Eloquent was already mentioned in the comment. [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)

If you go for an ORM instead of Eloquent's active record pattern Doctrine is the most popular project. [Doctrine Website](https://www.doctrine-project.org/)